# Can Boris Johnson request a Brexit extension to November 1st?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

The UK Parliament has passed a law mandating that the Prime Minister (currently Boris Johnson) must request an extension to the Brexit deadline by October 19th, unless a 'no-deal Brexit' has been approved by the UK Parliament.

However, could he just request a pointlessly short extension (i.e. to November 1st)? Is there anything in the wording of the bill that would prevent this?

Comment: The title and the body of the question ask opposite things, which makes it unnecessarily hard to understand the current answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see your point. Ok, I will edit to make the question more consistent.

Answer (score 14):

The PM cannot ask for a short [extension](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-no-deal-bill-vote-house-lords-boris-johnson-law-parliament-latest-a9094741.html) The legislation itself prevents it.

> Under the terms of the bill, Mr Johnson must request an extension to Brexit negotiations to the end of January next year unless he can secure a deal or parliamentary approval for no-deal by 19 October

The [commons library](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/brexit/negotiations/the-benn-burt-bill-another-article-50-extension/) has more insights that may be of interest.

The Bill as presented to the [Lords](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/bills/lbill/2017-2019/0202/18202.pdf) contains the following, as far as I know there were no relevant amendments.

> The Prime Minister must seek to obtain from the European Council an
>   extension of the period under Article 50(3) of the Treaty on European Union
>   ending at 11.00pm on 31 October 2019 by sending to the President of the
>   European Council a letter in the form set out in the Schedule to this Act
>   requesting an extension of that period to 11.00pm on 31 January 2020

> If the European Council decides to agree an extension of the period in Article
>   50(3) of the Treaty on European Union ending at 11.00 pm on 31 October 2019
>   to the period ending at 11.00pm on 31 January 2020, the Prime Minister must,
>   immediately after such a decision is made, notify the President of the European
>   Council that the United Kingdom agrees to the proposed extension.

Comment: It should be on legislation.gov.uk, but it isn't yet. The best I can find is the bill [as introduced into the Lords](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/bills/lbill/2017-2019/0202/18202.pdf), but I'm pretty sure they didn't pass any amendments.